# angularjs dynamic less stylesheets

Tags: angularjs, less

i am using the follow code to include dynamic less stylesheet in my angularjs project.

```
<link ng-repeat="stylesheet in getStylesheets track by $index" rel="{{ stylesheet.type }}" type="text/css" ng-href="{{ stylesheet.href }}" >
```

The issue is that the less.js cannot compile it on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to refresh this way:

```
localStorage.clear();
less.refresh();
```

From https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/346